# Definition of integers needs explaining

Tags: lambda-calculus

Zero and one are defined by the successor function.

$$
\begin{align*}
&0 ≡ λsz.z \\
&1 ≡ λsz.s(z)
\end{align*}
$$

But why? $λsz.z$ is irreducible to a value. If I call this function on some value, I get back $z$, which is merely a variable in itself. If I call the function on two values, I get back the second value, which is not necessarily zero.

And yet we're just assigning the function the value $0$? Why? Why not assign zero to say $λs.(λz.xyt)$. This seems arbitrary.

This is from the arithmetic section of:
http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS03/alpi/lambda.pdf

Comment: If you apply $\lambda s z.z$ to a value you get back $\lambda z.z$.  Note that $\lambda s z.z$ is shorthand for $\lambda s.\lambda z.z$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The natural numbers don't exist natively in the world of lambda calculus, and so if we want to use them, we have to define them somehow. You are describing the [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals), one possible definition which supports arithmetic. Church defines $n$ to be the function $(s,z) \mapsto s^{(n)}(z)$ that maps a pair $(s,z)$ into an $n$-fold application of $s$ to $z$. In particular, when $n = 0$ we get $(s,z) \mapsto z$.

Why this definition and not any other one? No reason. It is just a common definition, but you can use any other definition you like, or even come up with a new one. This particular definition supports arithmetic – you can define addition, multiplication and so on. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Calculation_with_Church_numerals) for the details.

Comment: Thanks. It still feels very opaque. If integers don't exist natively and we want to define them, them why not say 1≡ 1 and so on---just wholesale include them?  I feel like this is a more common definition of numbers. You say there’s no reason for the Church definition. However, my definition does have a good reason behind it--- it is simple, immediately transparent, and is a convention both within and without this field. // In other words, what’s the advantage of such a definition?

Comment: You don't have "1" in lambda calculus, just like you don't have pigs and orcas there. If you want "1" then you have to define it as a lambda term.

Comment: to create lambda calculus, I’m sure various operators and ideas had to be defined. Before those definitions, lambda calculus wasn’t there. Something had to be axiomatic, right? Integers can also be defined axiomatically. Maybe I’m missing the point? Say we don’t to do it axiomatic. I’m reading the wikipedia entry. It seems to say that there is a function whose role is to generate integers. Each successive application increments by 1. So, in reality, it is not a definition of integers but rather a definition of addition. It’s a prefix function. Here’s a sensible, transparent shorthand: +^n x. x

Comment: Also, in the document I’m reading on lambda calculus (linked in my question), an example of multiplication is given as "The product of 2 by 2 is then:
(λxyz.x(yz))22
which reduces to
(λz.2(2z))" \\The author seems to be using integers within lambda calculus without defining them outside of addition. Is the author confused?

Comment: Everything in lambda calculus is a function. There are no "atoms". If we want to have "2" in our language, we have to define it as a lambda term; "2" is meant as a shortcut in your document. The Church numerals can be defined using the successor function, as you mention; this results in the same lambda terms. The point of the definition is that it allows us to define arithmetic operations. Not any definition of the successor function supports arithmetic, but this particular one does.

Comment: I think that the point that you're missing is that in lambda calculus we *don't* have to define the natural numbers axiomatically. Rather, we can define them inside the formalism. That's just like in set theory: we don't define the natural numbers as foreign axioms, since in set theory everything is a set. Instead, we define them using a successor operation. In lambda calculus, everything is a function, and so you have to define your numerals as functions.

Comment: I wish it was explained in those terms---especially because a very common avenue to lambda calculus is functional programming and not set theory. Thank you very much. I’ll write up an answer that summarizes these ideas.

Comment: Also, how is $λsz.s^{n}z$ applied? If n = 1 and I apply the function to a, I get then $(λsz.sz)a = λz.az = 1$? How is that equal to 1? Also. How can n = 1? We are using the integer 1 in the very definition of increasing something by 1, which doesn’t exist, all so that we can define the number 1. Seems . . . circular.

Comment: In $\lambda sz.s^nz$ we are using 1 in the metalanguage, just as we are using English when talking about the lambda calculus, even though English is not part of lambda calculus.  The Church numeral 1 is *by definition* the function $\lambda sz.sz$. The Church number system defines numerals and operations on them (all of these are lambda terms) such that the result is isomorphic to the natural numbers.

Comment: The number 1 per se doesn't belong to the lambda calculus. When we are using 1 in this particular context (of describing Church's system), we really mean the Church numeral 1. In other words, 1 is a shorthand for $\lambda sz.sz$, nothing more.

Comment: So, you’re saying that integers are part of the meta language used to help us describe lambda calculus. But we also want to create a definition of this meta language that is consistent from within the language of  lambda calculus itself. In other words, define the basic operations in terms of the meta language, then the rest can be taken care of with the constructs of the language

Comment: Not exactly. The basic operations are defined directly in the language. The only thing we need to define in the metalanguage is the mapping from "classical" natural numbers to their counterparts in the lambda calculus. There is no way around this, because this mapping crosses the language-metalanguage boundary.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now. If I could by you a beer, I would.

Comment: While I think what you are getting at is you can *technically* use any countably infinite set of (closed, normalized) lambda terms to represent numbers with some arbitrary mapping, I still would not use the words "there's no reason" for this particular definition.  As I'm sure you're aware, this definition identifies a number with the term which performs structural recursion over that number.  This definition can be read off of the inductive definition of the natural numbers.  One could argue that this is the only correct definition, e.g. by considering the polymorphic lambda calculus.